# Displaying Info

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

In a project for school, I'm required to make a menu system with the following options:

1. Load employees’ data - prompts user for the number of employees to be loaded and then prompts for each employee name, id (5 digit number), and annual salary
2. Add new employee - prompts user for an employee data, name, id, and annual salary
3. Display all employees - displays each employee’s data to the console, one employee per line
4. Retrieve specific employee’s data - prompts user for the employee id and displays the corresponding employee’s data: id, name, and salary
5. Retrieve employees with salaries based on range - prompts user for the lowest and highest salary and displays all employees with salaries in that range. Display each employee on separate line with all information - name, id, and salary
6. Exit

Each menu choice must be it's own be its own method, and he prefers we use arrays instead of lists, which is why I allotted 100 spaces. Here is what I have so far. Menu options 1, 2, and 6 run without breaking the program. But anything where things have to be displayed seems to break. My best guess is that there is an issue with passing and updating the array "employees" between all of the methods.

```
package practice;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project {
    
    public static Employee[] loadData() {
        Scanner scanint = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanstr = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("How many employees would you like to add?"); //Determines how many employees to create
        Employee[] employees = new Employee[100];
        int numberEmployees = scanint.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberEmployees; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter name: ");
            String empName = scanstr.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter ID: ");
            int empID = scanint.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Salary: ");
            int empSalary = scanint.nextInt();
            employees[i+1] = new Employee(empName, empID, empSalary); //Add employee to array
        }
        return employees;
    }
    
    public static Employee addEmployee() {
        Scanner scanint = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanstr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        String empName = scanstr.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter ID: ");
        int empID = scanint.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter salary: ");
        int empSalary = scanint.nextInt();
        return new Employee(empName, empID, empSalary);
    }
    
    public static void displayEmployees(Employee[] employees) {
        for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            if (employees[i] != null) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(employees));
                //System.out.println("Employee Name: " + employees[i].name + " ID: " + employees[i].id + " Salary: " + employees[i].salary);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void specificEmployee(Employee[] employees, int id) {
        for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            if (employees[i].id == id) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + employees[i].name + " ID: " + employees[i].id + " Salary: " + employees[i].salary);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("ID not recognized");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void salaryRange(Employee[] employees, int salaryMinimum, int salaryMaximum) {
        for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            if (employees[i].salary >= salaryMinimum && employees[i].salary <= salaryMaximum) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + employees[i].name + " ID: " + employees[i].id + " Salary: " + employees[i].salary);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("No employees within salary range");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scanint = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanstr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int menuChoice = 0;
        while (menuChoice != 6) {
            System.out.println("\tMenu:");
            System.out.println("1. Load Employee Data");
            System.out.println("2. Add New Employee");
            System.out.println("3. Display All Employees");
            System.out.println("4. Retrieve Specific Employee Data");
            System.out.println("5. Retrieve Employees Within Salary Range");
            System.out.println("6. Exit");
        
            menuChoice = scanint.nextInt();
            Employee[] employees = new Employee[100];
            int amountEmployees;
        
        
            
            if (menuChoice == 1) {
                employees = loadData();
            }
            else if (menuChoice == 2) {
                employees[0] = addEmployee();
            }
            else if (menuChoice == 3) {
                displayEmployees(employees);
            }
            else if (menuChoice == 4) {
                System.out.println("Enter 5 digit employee ID: ");
                int id = scanint.nextInt();
                specificEmployee(employees, id);
            }
            else if (menuChoice == 5) {
                System.out.println("Enter minimum of salary range: ");
                int salaryMinimum = scanint.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter maximum of salary range");
                int salaryMaximum = scanint.nextInt();
                salaryRange(employees, salaryMinimum, salaryMaximum);
            }
            else if (menuChoice == 6) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
            }

        }
        scanint.close();
        scanstr.close();

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!!!

Comment: You should probably include an integer for each array that defines the number of elements used. Also, unless you set each element to null, then the elements aren't guaranteed to be null.

Comment: Your second menu item only sets element 0 of the array. You can't add two or more employees. I would suggest spending some time in learning how to use your ide's debugger.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code:

```
while (menuChoice != 6) {
            System.out.println("\tMenu:");
            System.out.println("1. Load Employee Data");
            System.out.println("2. Add New Employee");
            System.out.println("3. Display All Employees");
            System.out.println("4. Retrieve Specific Employee Data");
            System.out.println("5. Retrieve Employees Within Salary Range");
            System.out.println("6. Exit");
        
            menuChoice = scanint.nextInt();
            **Employee[] employees = new Employee[100];**
            int amountEmployees;
        
        
            
            if (menuChoice == 1) {
                employees = loadData();
            }
```

You have declared the employees array inside the while loop, so each time you read an input you are creating a new one. This totally defeats the purpose of storing employees in an array and later retrieving them, which also makes the assignment redundant if `menuChoice == 1`. You must think about where you should declare your array.

```
public static void specificEmployee(Employee[] employees, int id) {
        for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            if (employees[i].id == id) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + employees[i].name + " ID: " + employees[i].id + " Salary: " + employees[i].salary);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("ID not recognized");
            }
        }
    }
```

When you declare an array, the values by default are null, unless you assign them some values. Here, you are iterating the entire array and checking for employee id. You should consider what would happen if the employee at a particular index in the array is null. You must have checks for such cases.

A similar problem is in one of the other methods that you have created. I will let you debug that on your own.

And as suggested by @NomadMaker - Your second menu item only sets element 0 of the array. You can't add two or more employees.

I would suggest, you try to dry run your code and if you find it tough, try debugging it in an ide.